# Laravel 7 error when set APP_DEBUG to TRUE in .env?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel 7 application. However it has a problem changing APP_DEBUG to TRUE.

I removed maximebf/debugbar and barryvdh/laravel-debugbar from composer, then reinstalled them. But the problem persists.

This is the response I got from my application.

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper::setDumpHeader() must be of the type string, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\maximebf\debugbar\src\DebugBar\DataFormatter\DebugBarVarDumper.php on line 288
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Delete the file `/bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: I've done it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This looks related to https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar/issues/474 - bugs should be reported at the package maintainer's issue trackers

Comment: check your composer.lock and also use this command  php artisan optimize:clear